# CSS formatting issues, divs moving each other and divs not centering

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, web-deployment

Basically I have this title that says testing. On large screens it isn't centered, and is moved to the right. I want it to be centered, but I can't get it centered. On smaller screens it is to the right of the images and pushing them left, keeping nothing centered. In all cases I want it to be below the images and centered in the page. Thanks.

I keep trying aligns, floats, widths, and margins/ padding but nothing works.

```
    <div class="primary-content">
   <span class="title">FTC TEAM 4466</span>
      <a href="#egg">egg</a>


        <div class="bot-pod">
          <div class="bot">
               <img src="img/finalbot.svg" alt="old robot">
            </div>
            <div class="pod">
               <img src="img/finalpod.svg" alt="old robot">
            </div>
         </div>


  <div class="team">
          <span class="title">testing</span>
          <h1>4466</h1>
          <span class="egg">        <p>
      <a href="#egg">egg</a>
    </p></span>
  </div><!-- End  -->

    </div><!-- End .primary-content -->
```

```
body {
  color: #000;
  font: 1em/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

.primary-content{
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Abolition Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15rem;
  padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  display:block;
}


.bot {
float:left;
width:47%;
padding:1px 1px 1px 1px; 
margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
}

.pod {
float:right;
width:47%;
padding:1px 1px 1px 1px; 
margin: 90.66px 1px 90.66px 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .bot {
text-align:center;
width:100%;
padding:0; 
margin: 0;
}

.pod {
text-align:center;
width:100%;
padding:0; 
margin: 0;
}
  img[src="img/finalbot.svg"]{
    width:70%;
    align-content:center;
}

img[src="img/finalpod.svg"]{
    width:70%;
    align-content:center;
}
}
```

I though that the div being below the other ones in the code would do it, but it just doesn't. I think the issue on big screens may be that .bot and .pod are different heights, but I dob't know how to make them equal as it changes as the page gets smaller and bigger. I don't know why my issue is happening for the small screens (under 1300px width).
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set display to `flex` and add `justify.content:center` to the CSS properties of the `div` you are trying to center.

Answer (score 0):

this could happen because you are using an  tag in the title,
span tags can not get centered, change this for an h1 tag or another

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to your code and this is what I came up with:

Feel free to use it

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  font: 1em/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

.primary-content{
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Abolition Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15rem;
  padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  display:block;
  align-content:center;
}


.bot {
float:left;
width:47%;
padding:1px 1px 1px 1px; 
margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
}

.pod {
float:right;
width:47%;
padding:1px 1px 1px 1px; 
margin: 90.66px 1px 90.66px 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {

.primary-content{
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Abolition Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  display:block;
  align-content:center;
}

  .bot {
text-align:center;
width:100%;
padding:0; 
margin: 0;
}

.pod {
text-align:center;
width:100%;
padding:0; 
margin: 0;
}
  img[src="img/finalbot.svg"]{
    width:70%;
    align-content:center;
}

img[src="img/finalpod.svg"]{
    width:70%;
    align-content:center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-content">
   <h2>FTC TEAM 4466</h2>
      <a href="#egg">egg</a>


        <div class="bot-pod">
          <div class="bot">
               <img src="img/finalbot.svg" alt="old robot">
            </div>
            <div class="pod">
               <img src="img/finalpod.svg" alt="old robot">
            </div>
         </div>


  <div class="team">
          <h2>testing</h2>
          <h2>4466</h2>
          <p><a href="#egg">egg</a></p>
  </div><!-- End  -->

    </div><!-- End .primary-content -->
```